# Error for calling method

Tags: java, method-call

I am trying to call back this method for an if-else statement, but I keep getting an error such as ".class is expected" and all.

Here is my code:

```
public static void display(String[] date,int index,int arraylength)
{
    for (index=0;index<arraylength;index++)
    {
        System.out.println("The date ["+index+"]: "+date[index]);
    }
    //this is the method which is for display an array element
    if (pass.equals("BERKAT123"))
    {
        display(String[] date;int index;int arraylength);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Incorrect password"); 
        start();
    }
} 
//this is where the method will be call...
```

Seems like I screw up the parameters. Can someone tell me how to write the correct parameters?

Comment: update your error also

Comment: '.class' expected
        display(String[] date;int index;int arraylength);

Comment: directly pass value like display(date, index arraylength)

Comment: thanks man for helping me...my code works now :)

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand your problem clearly. But as far as i understood, you need to define your "display" function something like this -

```
public static void display(String[] date){ //here take the date array as the only parameter
    for(int index=0;index<date.length;index++){
       System.out.println("Date with index " +index+ " is: "+date[index]);
    }
}
```

Now in the "main" function populate the String date[] array according to your requirement and all the other variables you need. Then check for your if-else condition and call the "display" function inside it like this -

```
if (pass.equals("BERKAT123")){
   display(date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke the function like

```
if (pass.equals("BERKAT123")){
  display(date,index,arraylength);
}
```

instead of

```
if (pass.equals("BERKAT123")){
  display(String[] date;int index;int arraylength);
}
```

You need to write down the types of the variables (String[], int) when you **define** the function, but not when you **invoke** it.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand difference between parameter and arguments,

- parameter used in function/method definition.
- arguments used in function/method call.

You need to invoke the method like this `display(date,index,arraylength);` instead of `display(String[] date;int index;int arraylength);`.

I'm explaining **arguments** and **perameters** and how to call method,

```
public static int sum(int x, int y) { //x, y are parameters here
        return x + y;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 10;
        int y = 20;
        int add = sum(x, y); //x, y are arguments here
        System.out.println("ADDITION IS: " +add);
    }
```